# Colors not decoded with Laravel's Homestead using Git Bash

Tags: laravel, git-bash, homestead

I am using Git Bash on a Windows Server 2008 machine which is running Homestead 2.0.7. When I am running commands it is not decoding the colors so I get something like this...

[image: Scrrenshot of Git Bash]

I have enabled hhvm to run on Homestead, not sure if this is what is effecting it?

How can I get it to output correctly?

Thanks

Comment: I may be wrong, but the Windows CLI does not support ANSI colors. Switch to Linux.

Comment: An alternative would be to use [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Conosle2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) in combination with [Ansicon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon) which adds ANSI color support to windows.

- Install Console2
- Copy `ansicon` into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Console2\ansicon`
- use `ansicon -i` to install (`ansicon -u` to uninstall). Install x86 version for use with git bash.